# Sorting a data table based on sort order from another data table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 data tables, one in which i have my data(D1) with a unique data Id and in another data table(D2) i have the Ids of all the records of my data table(D1) in a particular order.How can i sort my data table(D1) based on the order of Ids in D2.I am using c# asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the rows in the ordering table into a `Dicationary` with an index. Assuming your key field is named `Key` the code might look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dt = new DataTable("Data");
    var dtOrder = new DataTable("Order");

    // Insert some data here

    int i = 0;
    var orderDict = new Dictionary<object, int>();
    foreach(DataRow row in dtOrder.Rows)
    {
        orderDict.Add(row["Key"], ++i);
    }

    var ordered = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(r => orderDict[r["Key"]]);
}
```

As I read Peaceman71's comment, I think it is worth mentioning that this is a *disconnected* approach. Any proper database software will do this for you as well.

Comment: ok this query sorts only one column of the data table D1 based on D2, i want to sort the entire data table D1 based on the Id in D2

Comment: No, that's no fully true. `ordered` is an `IOrderedEnumerable<DataRow>` and contains the full rows of `dt` / `D1`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to do this in the code or in the database.

In the database you would join the two tables, such as (MS-SQL/T-SQL):

```
SELECT D2.Sort, D1.* FROM D2 LEFT JOIN D1 ON D2.ID = D1.ID ORDER BY D2.Sort
```

In code it depends very much on where you keep the data. DataSet, DataTables etc.

Comment: i want a way to do this in c# code...i have data as 2 data tables

Comment: Thank you for the clarifacation. Then you have got a good answer from Mudu.

Comment: You may also make a DataSet and add the two tables, and a relationship. But, I think this approach is more effort to do the same.

Comment: Moreover, you could join the two data tables with plain LINQ to objects and order them by the second datatable's records' order. Similar to Peaceman71's SQL, just in LINQ.